# Access a div specific variable from inside ng-class

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

For one of my projects, I have a div with three conditional ng-class, looking like:

```
<div name="type" ng-class="{'class-one' : stringVariable != "type", 'class-two': stringVariable == "type" && booleanTrue, 'class-three': stringVariable == "type" && !booleanTrue}">My type div.</div>
```

This works as I want it to run, the problem being when I have several div using the same functionality:

```
<div name="type" ng-class="{'class-one' : stringVariable != "type", 'class-two': stringVariable == "type" && booleanTrue, 'class-three': stringVariable == "type" && !booleanTrue}">My type div.</div>
<div name="date" ng-class="{'class-one' : stringVariable != "date", 'class-two': stringVariable == "date" && booleanTrue, 'class-three': stringVariable == "date" && !booleanTrue}">My date div.</div>
<div name="name" ng-class="{'class-one' : stringVariable != "name", 'class-two': stringVariable == "name" && booleanTrue, 'class-three': stringVariable == "name" && !booleanTrue}">My name div.</div>
```

Again, this works but seems inefficient and unwieldy. Every time a div uses this functionality, I end up having to change the variable inside each ng-class' expression, and any future refactoring will be a major pain in the bottom.

I am trying to find a way to define a variable inside the div and then use it inside the ng-class, such as for example something looking like:

```
<div name="type" ng-class="{'class-one' : stringVariable != $this.name, 'class-two': stringVariable == $this.name && booleanTrue, 'class-three': stringVariable == $this.name && !booleanTrue}">My type div.</div>
```

Unfortunately, and maybe obviously, this doesn't work.

Is there a way to make this kind of things work?

---

- *Note1: if it is not possible I will define the classes through the controller, but I would really like to find a way to make it work through ng-class*
- *Note2: I would like to avoid using an external directive if possible*

Comment: This seems like a good time to create your own directive.

Comment: @ryanyuyu But I don't want to... :'( More seriously, I find it strange that there is no way to do something like `<div myVariable="type" ng-class="{'class-one': myVariable === scopeVariable}">`, I would have thought this kind of things would be basic and useful

Comment: You could also define objects in the controller then bind like `<div name="obj.name" ng-class="{'class-one' : stringVariable != obj.name'}"> `but that's basically what an element directive would better encapsulate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the answer was, as suggested by Tushar, to move all the logic to a separate function, and return ng-class names that way.

As a result, we have in the template:

```
<div ng-class="myMethod("type")">
```

And in the Controller:

```
myMethod : function(stringVariable){
  if (this.$scope.stringVariable == stringVariable) {
    if (this.$scope.booleanTrue) {
      return 'class-two';
    } else {
      return 'class-three';
    }
  } else {
    return 'class-one';
  }
}
```

Comment: Note: I tried to put this as an edit to @Tushar's answer, but it was rejected.

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution could be just use scope methods inside the template instead of variables. That way your can update the internal code of the method but the method name remains same and that mostly prevents the breaking due to refactor of logic.

So you can try this :

```
<div name="type" ng-class="{'class-one' : isValidForType()}"
```

Where isValidForType is a scope method and you can also pass data to that method if you need to access something special to that div.

Comment: This seems like a good solution.  Although within the ng-class you can simply call the function and return the class name in the logic like  `ng-class="isValidForType('type')"`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how that works, sorry :/ In my example, I have three divs with different names, each with three ng-class. Would I put isValidForType() for each ng-class, in each div?

Comment: Ok, I got it. I will detail a bit this answer in the coming days before accepting it